# How to use Ansible to label the nodes of K8S

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

At present, I can only get the host name of the host node by going to the corresponding node to store the file locally, and then I send the stored file to the master node and set the file as a registered variable to set the corresponding node label for k8s, but for more The configuration of each node is difficult. Is there any good way to achieve it?

```
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes
  tags: gets
  tasks:
    - name: install the latest version of rsync
      yum:
        name: rsync
        state: latest

    - name: Ansible gets the current hostname
      debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_hostname']    
      register: result
    - local_action:
        module: copy
        content: "{{ result }}"
        dest: /tmp/Current_hostname.yml
    - debug: msg="{{ item }}"
      with_lines: cat /tmp/Current_hostname.yml |tr -s ' '|cut -d '"' -f6 |sort -o /tmp/Modified_hostname

- hosts: "{{ hosts | default('k8s-master') }}"
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tags: gets
  tasks:
    - name: install the latest version of rsync
      yum:
        name: rsync
        state: latest

    - name: Transfer file from ServerA to ServerB
      synchronize:
        src: /tmp/Modified_hostname
        dest: /tmp/Modified_hostname
        mode: pull
      delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ groups['mysql'][0] }}"

- hosts: "{{ hosts | default('k8s-master') }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tags: gets
  become: yes
  vars:
    k8s_mariadb: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/Modified_hostname') }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Gets the node host information
      debug: msg="the value of is {{ k8s_mariadb }}"

    - name: Tag MySQL fixed node
      shell: kubectl label node {{ k8s_mariadb }} harbor-master1=mariadb
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what is preventing you from, on `hosts["k8s-master"]`, `shell: kubectl label node {{ groups['mysql'][0] | regex_replace("whatever you are doing to it", "whatever else") }} harbor-master1=mariadb` ?

Comment: If I use local_action so that I can only use the current host, I can’t get other host names locally, nor can I classify the local host names into nodes that are placed on k8s-master. Now my problem wants to get the node The host name is placed on the k8s-master node in the form of a file, so that I can mark the k8s node in turn by registering variables

Comment: Sorry, my hosts file is the ip address. I got it and it doesn’t solve the problem. The hosts file can’t be changed to the host name. I feel sorry

Comment: In which case would this do what you want? `label node {{ hostvars[ groups.mysql[0] ].ansible_hostname }}`, since as long as its within the same ansible-playbook run, all hosts have access to all hostvars from other hosts